# Как поставить DLE на Apache?

Tags: apache, dle

Как поставить dle 9.3 на apache сервер, не используя denwer, а когда все по отдельности установлено?

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы не изменяли рабочую директорию (DocumentRoot) в файле ApacheApache2confhttpd.conf, то просто закиньте файлы DLE в директорию ApacheApache2htdocs и дальше устанавливайте, как устанавливали до этого. А вообще очень рекомендую прочитать документацию, она есть [даже на русском языке](http://www.apache.ru/docs/apache-2.0/).